# Running a python script on executors in a cluster [Scala/Spark]

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I have python script:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
  print("hello " + line)
```

And I run it on workers in cluster:

```
def run(spark: SparkSession) = {

  val data = List("john","paul","george","ringo")

  val dataRDD = sc.makeRDD(data)
  val scriptPath = getClass.getResource("test.py").getPath
  val pipeRDD = dataRDD.pipe(command = "python3 " ++ scriptPath)

  pipeRDD.foreach(println)
}
```

**Output**

hello john

hello ringo

hello george

hello paul

I have a few questions, please tell me.
Can I access the spark session in a python script?
Or can I create a file in my python script and save it to the hdfs file system?

Actually, that's what I'm trying to do
I want to create csv files in a python script, and save them to hdfs.

And one more minor question.
Is it possible to send commands to the workers to install python packages?

For example: *pip install pandas*

!UPD:
I have made some changes to the python file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#import pandas as pd
import sys
import os

for line in sys.stdin:
    with open('readme.csv', 'w') as f:
        f.write('Name,Last Name\nМихаил,Зубенко')

print(os.getcwd() + '/readme.csv')
```

The file is created inside the container:

[image]

Now I have one question. How do I access this file?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I access the spark session in a python script

Not with a piped command, no.

> files in Python script

For starters, I suggest you use PySpark rather than Scala, assuming you "need" Python.

```py
rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(["john","paul","george","ringo"])
hello = rdd.mapValues(lambda s: "hello " + s)
for s in rdd.collect():
  print(s)
```

> create a file ... and save it to the hdfs file system ...

Alternatively, you can also write to HDFS from Scala. Not really clear why you need Python at all. Scala can create/read CSV files as well.

> install python packages [on workers]

Is it possible, yes, however, PySpark already provides support for this with the use of ZIP/EGG files during `spark-submit` and `--py-files` argument

> for example, pandas

SparkSQL DataFrames mostly replace the need for Pandas, and you should use them rather than RDDs

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I can't give up the python script. It contains a lot of functionality for creating csv files.

Comment: The Python script shown in the question does nothing with CSV files

Comment: Also `import csv` module isn't really compatible with Spark's own `DataFrameWriter.csv()` method

Comment: Okay, I'll watch. I simplified the example script to show the idea. Now I'm interested. Can I save files to hdfs through this python script.

Comment: The peculiarity is that I need to send this script to the cluster via a scala application.

Comment: Through what script? As mentioned, you should be using `DataFrameWriter` class methods to write to HDFS

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't abandon the python script. And he creates and saves files. As a result, I'm trying to find a way to run this python script in my scala application.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: 1) I suggest you open a new question since I've answered your original questions 2) `piped.collect()` returns an arraylist of strings. You need to use something like `pipped.toDF("lines").write.csv("hdfs-path)` instead, after a `import spark.implicits._`. You also need to remove the last line that outputs the filename. Alternatively, I fail to understand how difficult it is to rewrite 8 lines of Python code into Scala

Comment: Actually I have 1000 lines of code =). This is a simplified example. 
Line 8 cannot be removed, it returns the path to the file back to the scala application.

Comment: How about you remove all the file writing methods and replace them with regular print calls? Then when you call the script with RDD pipe method, you directly get all the lines of text without needing to read any files?

Comment: oh my god. It's a great idea. I'll have to try.